# Как отправить подарок (Гифт, Gift) Steam при помощи бота node-js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, steam

Как отправить Steam-подарок с помощью бота на nodejs?

Я нашел несколько статей по этой теме, и везде эти ссылки указаны:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/steam-user

https://www.npmjs.com/package/steam-tradeoffer-manager

https://github.com/DoctorMcKay/node-steamcommunity/

Но на мой взгляд, туда можно отправлять только сделки, а Gift нельзя!

Если вы знаете, как отправлять подарки с помощью Steam-бота, используя эти или другие ссылки, пожалуйста, помогите, заранее спасибо!

Comment: с помощью steam bot api можно послать подарок-гифт-gift?

Comment: Ну я знаю что как то можно, а как именно, sendGift({...}) ???